# блок посередине а слева и справа от него текст

Tags: html, css

Блок должен быть посередине а вне его ,слева и справа ,текст который выровнен ближе к блоку то есть по правой стороне и левой стороне и всё это должно быть в одну строку
вот мой пример

```
<div>
  какой нибудь текст 
  <center> <span> </span> </center> 
  тоже текст 
</div>
```

в моём примере он просто ставит span посередине и переносит текст вверх и вниз

Comment: Ага, мы поняли. Делайте.

Comment: Очень хорошо, какой у Вас бюджет?

Comment: чего все такие злые 
вот мой пример 
`<div>
какой нибудь текст
<center>
<span>
</span>
</center>
тоже текст
</div>`
в моём примере он просто ставит span посередине и переносит текст вверх и вниз

Comment: Тег `<center></center>` из бабушкиного сундука достал?

Comment: [center](https://webref.ru/html/center)

Comment: center удалили из html5 на сколько я знаю

Answer (score 3):

Вот так вроде бы, да ??

```css
.flex{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  width:300px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid;
}

.block{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  какой нибудь текст 
   <div class="block"> </div> 
  тоже текст 
</div>
```